# How to apply sorting slide animation using javascript and jquery when the <ul> displays on screen

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

My requirement is I want to display sorting with price with slide animation when another value is coming from another api.There are total 5 apis. The animation is like we usually see in any league matches were the player with lowest ranks comes up with animation or in any games.

Here is my code(It is in .cshtml):

```
<ul id="externalPharmacyList" @* data-aos="fade-up" *@></ul>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var data1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
var data2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
var jsonData = data1.concat(data2);

function displaySortedData() {
    // Modify the sorting function to compare copay values as numbers
    var sortedJsonData = jsonData.sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.copay) - parseFloat(b.copay);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedJsonData.length; i++) {
        var item = sortedJsonD`your text`ata[i];
        var fullAddress = item.address1 + " " + item.address2 + " " + item.city + " " + item.state + " " + item.zipCode;

        var listItemHtml = `
            <li style="display:none;">
                <div class="b-m-pharmacy-det">
                    <div class="b-p-name">
                        ${item.pharmacyName}
                        <small>${fullAddress}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="b-m-qty">
                        ${item.quantity} ${item.drugName}
                    </div>
                    <div class="b-m-price" style="text-align:right">
                        ${item.copay}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>`;

        $('#externalPharmacyList').append(listItemHtml);
    }

    // Apply the slide animation to the list items
    $('#externalPharmacyList li').slideDown();
   }

// Call the displaySortedData function after both data sets are concatenated
  displaySortedData();
 });
```

In this code the value is coming in model from soap api which I am converting it into json then similar I again call that api and sorting it in another variable. Then I am concating both the json data. After that that I am sorting the incoming json data and then applying slidedown animation. I might be wrong here bcoz I want to apply animation while sorting. It would be really helpful if anyone can guide me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point here is not only to sort the data but also to animate the reordering of the list items.Your current approach involves appending sorted items to the list and then using slideDown for the animation. However, slideDown is much better for revealing hidden elements rather than sorting animations.

I think you'd better first display the list items without sorting. This gives a starting point for the animation.

Assuming jsonData is your API response and after seeing your json data, I added the code inside a simple HTML template for testing. I added button that simulates the change of JSON data (or in other words arrival of new data). It is now working and showing the animations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sorting and Updating</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .b-m-pharmacy-det { border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 10px 0; padding: 10px; }
        .b-p-name, .b-m-qty, .b-m-price { margin-bottom: 5px; }
        button { margin: 20px 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="addNewItemButton">Add New Item</button>
<ul id="externalPharmacyList"></ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonData = [
        { "pharmacyName": "Pharmacy A", "address1": "123 Main St", "address2": "", "city": "CityA", "state": "ST", "zipCode": "12345", "phone": "123-456-7890", "copay": "$15.20", "drugName": "Drug A", "quantity": "30" },
        { "pharmacyName": "Pharmacy B", "address1": "456 Elm St", "address2": "", "city": "CityB", "state": "ST", "zipCode": "67890", "phone": "987-654-3210", "copay": "$10.50", "drugName": "Drug B", "quantity": "60" }
    ];

    function displaySortedData() {
        var sortedJsonData = jsonData.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.copay.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,"")) - parseFloat(b.copay.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
        });

        $('#externalPharmacyList').empty();

        sortedJsonData.forEach(function(item, index) {
            var fullAddress = item.address1 + " " + item.address2 + " " + item.city + " " + item.state + " " + item.zipCode;

            var listItemHtml = `
                <li>
                    <div class="b-m-pharmacy-det">
                        <div class="b-p-name">
                            ${item.pharmacyName}
                            <small>${fullAddress}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="b-m-qty">
                            ${item.quantity} ${item.drugName}
                        </div>
                        <div class="b-m-price" style="text-align:right">
                            ${item.copay}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>`;

            $(listItemHtml).hide().appendTo('#externalPharmacyList').delay(index * 100).fadeIn(500);
        });
    }

    // Function to add a new item to jsonData and then update the list
    $('#addNewItemButton').click(function() {
        // Sample new item
        var newItem = {
            "pharmacyName": "Pharmacy C",
            "address1": "789 Oak St",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "CityC",
            "state": "ST",
            "zipCode": "10112",
            "phone": "555-123-4567",
            "copay": "$12.30",
            "drugName": "Drug C",
            "quantity": "45"
        };

        // Add the new item to jsonData
        jsonData.push(newItem);

        // Update the list
        displaySortedData();
    });

    // Initial display
    displaySortedData();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You should just try to implement a similar approach to click event of the button here to get triggered when you JSON data gets changed. In order to be able to test it, I added the script inside a sample HTML template but you can change it to `.cshtml`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Naser. I ran the code but it is neither sorting nor the animation is working. As u recommended i am first filling the json data then sorting.

Comment: @SandeepVerma Can you provide a piece of your JSON code if possible? The code that I provided might need some changes.

Comment: sure , here is the json data = [
    {
        "pharmacyName": "SAFEWAY PHARMACY #1266",
        "address1": "11290 DONNER PASS RD",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "TRUCKEE",
        "state": "CA",
        "zipCode": "96161",
        "phone": "530-582-7952",
        "copay": "$10.15",
        "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium Tab 40 MG (Base Equivalent)",
        "quantity": "30"
    }]..I want to sort it according to copay

Comment: @SandeepVerma I edited my answer, I think this must work know and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Naser. It is working but that animation is not proper do u have any idea about that kbc sorting animation where participant in fingerfirst who answered in less time that animation appears. It would be really helpful.

Comment: @SandeepVerma I'm happy that it worked. When it comes to the animation you can change the code to get different types of jquery animations or implement your own animation but I don't have any idea about the kbc sorting animation.